# Unable to understand correct use of None intent in LUIS

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have an app in LUIS with one intent "Help" (appart from None) and when I test it with utterances that my intent does not cover (e.g "Hi man"), LUIS resolves to the "Help" intent... I have no utterances in "None" intent...

What should I do? Should I add all the utterances I don't want to match "Help" intent in "None"?
Should I need to know everything a user can ask to my bot which is not related with "Help"?
For me, that's not make sense at all... and I think that is exactly how LUIS works...

Answer (score 0):

Intent are the action which we define, None is predefined Intent which come along with every LUIS model that you create , coming back to your problem. You have only define one intent i.e "help" so whenever LUIS gets the any query it will show the highest scoring intent i.e. "help". whenever you create an intent make to sure to save at least 5-6 co-related utterance, so that LUIS can generate a pattern out of it 'more you define co-related utterance better accuracy of result you will get'
if you want LUIS to respond on "HI man" create a new intent 'greet' save some utterance let LUIS do the remaining task, lastly about None intent If any user input 'asdsafdasdsfdsf' string like this. Your bot should be able to handle it respond accordingly like 'this asdsafdasdsfdsf is irrelevant to me' in simple term 'any irregular action that user want bot to perform come under none intent' i hope this will help

Comment: I think you missunderstood my question (or I don't explain myself clear enough, sorry). I don't want to respond to "Hi man" with a new intent, I just want LUIS to execute the "None" intent when a message does not match "Help" intent. And that is not happening, everything message goes to "Help".

Answer (score 0):

You can check the score of the Luis intent and then accordingly send the default response from code. For the utterances which are configured will have a greater score. Also, Luis app shud be balanced in terms of utterances configured as there is not a defined way that u can point utterances to None intent. Please check this link for best practices.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-best-practices. Also to highlight Luis does not work in terms of keyword matching to the utterances which you have configured. It works in terms of data you add in Luis in respective intents.